# REST Services Using spray-can

Tags: sbt, spray

I have an application that I'm building using spray-can. It is an sbt project and I have the standard sbt project structure. I have an application.dev.conf, application.test.conf and application.prod.conf. I now want to start my spray-can server by passing the application.xxx.conf file as argument. I have used Play framework extensively in the past and I can control or rather pass the configuration file to the play run command. How could I now do the same with Spray? Any suggestions?

I have the following:

```
val cfg = context.system.settings.config
```

Is this the correct way to get hold of the application.conf file inside my actor in Spray?

I tried doing this:

```
sbt "project simple-http-server" run -Dconfig.resource=production.conf
```

It seems that whatever that comes after run is silently ignored. How can I issue the run command against different configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Typesafe's Config Library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/)

Just define the dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
```

In your app you use this to get hold of the configuration:

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
```

By default it searches the classpath for a file named `application.{conf,json,properties}` but you can override this using `-Dconfig.file` when you run your app.

If you want this to work from within SBT you need to enable [forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Forking.html). SBT is normally not forking a new JVM process therefore you need to enable it and also specify the required JVM options in `build.sbt`:

```
// fork a new JVM for 'run' and 'test:run'
fork in run := true

// set config file to production.conf
javaOptions in run += "-Dconfig.file=production.conf"
```

Or set it dynamically at the command line:

```
sbt '; set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.file=production.conf"; run'
```

Comment: I want to be able to do sbt run -Dconfig.file application.prod.conf, so effectively I want to use a specific application conf file control when I start sbt . If I use javaOptions, would that mean that it uses the production.conf as the defailt?

Comment: Yes, instead you can also pass it at command line level. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I wanted!